# I am trying to install new template for Joomla 3.2 and i have an error for any template

Tags: templates, joomla

I have Joomla 3.2 and after installation, i want to install new template for a website i want to create, and every template i try to install i have this message

> Warning JInstaller: :Install: Cannot find XML setup file

this message apears for example trying to install this template

http://www.templatesjoomla.net/index.php/joomla3-x/286-global-solutions-joomla-3-joomla-25.html

What i am doing wrong ? THX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the problem being is that you're trying to install the downloaded zip, however if you open it up, you will see there there is a zip inside it, along with a folder called "**extensions**". So simply extract the zip file that you have downloaded first and upload the one called "**as002037free**" which is the template.

The zip file specifically says "unzipfirst" in the name ;)